# In a bash script, what's the best way to treat all errors as a success exit but the last one?

Tags: bash, macos, error-handling

Say you have a bash script of

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello" > hello
echo "world" > world

diff hello world
```

If any of the `echo` fails, exit with status code `0`.
`diff` should exit as normal with whatever exit code it returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is to do your error handling explicitly (which is to say, "by hand"). See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for a discussion of why and how the more automated approaches are error-prone (skipping the allegory up top for the exercises below if in a hurry).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello" > hello || exit 0
echo "world" > world || exit 0

# the shell will exit with the status of the last command by default
diff hello world
```

That said, if you **really** want to trust the shell's built-in error detection, you can do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# DON'T DO THIS if your logic is at all nontrivial, or if you can't answer all the exercise
# questions at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 correctly.

trap 'exit 0' ERR     # Start handling errors by exiting with status 0
echo "hello" > hello
echo "world" > world
trap - ERR            # Remove the ERR trap, falling back to default behavior

diff hello world
```

Comment: OP explicitly asks for the "best way", so maybe less is more :P

Comment: @thatotherguy, fair, but I'd rather foreclose someone else trying to be clever by adding the fancy-but-ill-advised answer myself (where it's possible to be explicit about the caveats).